# Convert 9-digit to a Readable Date

Tags: javascript, unix, timestamp

i'm grabbing some data from an app these data has a start and end time .

start : 539558971  , equivalent in readable date : 2020-12-06 12:45:00.000Z

end : 185424942 , equivalent in readable date : 2020-12-06 13:47:00.000Z

i don't know how to calculate it to get the correct date

this is what i tried :

```
const toDateTime = secs => {
    var t = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
    t.setSeconds(secs);
    return t;
}
```

output :

```
1987-02-05T21:29:31.000Z
1975-11-17T02:55:42.000Z
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Obviously a 3 times larger number of 9 digits is not going to be a 1 hour difference in time. That data probably doesnt mean what you think it means, its probably not time.

Comment: Also, when you go forward in time, the value decreases (`end` is smaller than `start`). That does not seem to make sense

Comment: var t = this.controlled;
this.setProgramDate({
        start: 1e3 * t.timestamp,
        end: t.preload_end,
        duration: t.timestamp - t.preload_end / 1e3
    }, t.programDate, t.progressBar),

this is what i found in their app.js

Comment: @jhon What you said in your question still does not make sense, based on this snippet. The snippet calculates a duration by basically doing `duration: start - end`. Which means that `end` happened before `start`. It makes sense in the snippet, because it refers to a preload_end time, and a start time which happens later, when it's ready. The date "equivalents" you wrote in your question don't make sense in this case, because you have the preload happen after the start... 